# How do I change position of button with insertion of a new row in html table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my button to shift its position down, everytime I create a new row in my table (using `table.insertRow()`). This is my code:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); //adds new row to the table on button click
})
```

Now, I have a button

```
<button id="change">Update</button>
```

I want this button, to keep on moving down everytime I press the `add` button to insert new rows in my table, such that the button remains below the table. How do I do that? Please help me.

Comment: Wrap them in a div and place the button below the table. That should do it

Comment: Tried it, not working. Its position doesn't change, with increase in table rows

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for that.